# LFS upload missing object but the file is there

Tags: git, github, git-lfs

I am trying to push a commit. But I keep getting an error saying:

```
error: GH008: Your push referenced at least 1 unknown Git LFS object
```

The file it is questioning is:

```
 (missing) SRP/com.unity.shadergraph/.data/texture_2d_lod_node.PNG (b262d71d68d478f6b6c3dc3086451a764e065b8608a65104e17cb8aefefa5f76)
```

Now I went to the folder and that file does exist:

[image: Screenshot of folder/file]

So my question is why does it keep giving me this error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like the object is somehow missing from the LFS object store. LFS objects are located at .git/lfs/objects. If your missing object was there it would be located at a path like b2/62/d71d68...

git-lfs adds objects when it runs the clean filter before staging files. Assuming the missing object is for the latest revision of the file, you can force the clean filter to rerun with a command like the following:

```
git add --renormalize path/to/file
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This fixed my issue when I was giving up hope.

Comment: thanks you so much, didnt know --renormalize could recover lfs objects.....

Answer (score 26):

This could happen you are migrating from one remote repository to another. Assuming the old repository is named `old-origin`,

```
git lfs fetch --all old-origin
git lfs push --all origin
```

should synchronize all LFS objects in your git commit history.

Comment: Thank you this solved my problem. My case was moving an old repository to new one.

Comment: This saved so much headache! Thank you!!

Comment: is there any reason you wrote `git lfs fetch <opt> <arg>` and then `git lfs push <arg> <opt>`, (switching the opt-arg order for arg-opt)?

Comment: @Groostav no idea! It [should work](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/main/docs/man/git-lfs-push.adoc) both ways. I will correct it so it s not confusing.

Answer (score 4):

That error means that your Git push contains a reference to a Git LFS object that was never uploaded to the server.

Try to run `git lfs push origin --all` to upload all local Git LFS objects. Afterwards `git push` should work.

---

**Background:**
Git LFS works by storing large files in a data storage outside of the Git repository. The separately stored files are then only referenced through so-called Git LFS pointer files in the Git repository (you can learn more in [Git LFS 101](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQzNfb4IwEY)). If a Git LFS user has a [misconfigured local client](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/2865), then it can happen that LFS files are added and locally referenced but not uploaded to the LFS data storage. Consequently, any other user of the repository would not be able to download the referenced LFS files and the repository would be stuck in a broken state. The `error: GH008: Your push referenced at least 1 unknown Git LFS object` protects the user from that situation.