# Transfer Git-LFS repository to a new one, with history

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, git-lfs

So we had a remote git server, but it "burned", now I try to push to a new repository a git repository with all history, but I get a (missing) obj lfs error

I tried `git lfs migrate` but did a mistake and all files transform to lfs so for one time it worked but mess up all history with lfs objects and all history is "lfs add", "lfs deleted"

Now `git lfs migrate` works well but when I try to push it show same error `(missing) PathToFile (4750fda193ad9d6cd94e7df41afb74f3379c53291515f92dbd619d99eb951069)`

What can I do to push properly with all history remaining?

Update: I tried doing

1 `git  fetch --prune`

2 `git add --renormalize .`

3 `git push --prune git@example.com:/new-location.git +refs/remotes/origin/*:refs/heads/* +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*`

In the end when pushing is showing same error as `(missing) PathToFIle (...)`

Comment: 'but I get a (missing) obj lfs error' --- in what step? what command?

Comment: @LeiYang when I try to push to empty remote repository. In general I tried prune, migrate, on local everything is fine, the problem is in pushin on remote

Comment: please paste your commands.

Comment: `git lfs push origin develop` - are u talking about this?

Comment: i've never used lfs. but can you explain why you use?

Comment: Because simple git can't push files more than 100mb, I have files 500mb or more

Comment: is it possible, to ask the git admin to transfer the entire repo(as zip file), to the new server filesystem?

Comment: @LeiYang no, it was a private repository like a private server, and nothing left, only local .git. This is the problem

Comment: i mean, is the new remote git server owned by your IT admins?

Comment: @LeiYang a private server, but use git lab system, in general yes

Comment: then don't need git push, just (compress your files then) use some removable media to copy to the server.

Comment: Not an option, I need to fix this from my computer

Comment: Have you tried [this (lower section)](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2013/05/how-to-properly-mirror-a-git-repository/) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LFS upload missing objectt but the file is there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52612880/lfs-upload-missing-objectt-but-the-file-is-there)

Comment: @Orace No it doesn’t, prune didn’t work for me, and lfs push either, I searched for all stackoverflow and didn’t find anything that worked for me, this is why I asked myself

Comment: @Orace link doesn't mention prune but rather `git add --renormalize path/to/file`

Comment: I don't know whether there is any solution to the problem (because the large objects *may* be irretrievable) and if so what it is, but Git itself can't help you here as it does not have the objects in question. Only LFS or backups can help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really an expert of git but [git lfs migrate](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/wiki/Tutorial#migrating-existing-repository-data-to-lfs) is not for migrating your repository to a new server!

It is rather for

> converting an existing Git repository to use Git LFS

In your case, however, it sounds like your repository already **is** using LFS so you don't want to use `git lfs migrate` at all.

---

What you rather want to do is migrate an existing local repository which uses LFS to a server.

If I understand [this post](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2013/05/how-to-properly-mirror-a-git-repository/) correctly then you could do the following steps

```
git fetch --prune
```

See

> **Cleaning old references to remote branches**
>
> By default, when you do a git fetch or git pull, git will not delete the references to branches that were deleted in the upstream repository (you may view them in your .git/refs/remotes dir). We need to clean those old references before mirroring them to a new location.
>
> To do so, run
>
> ```
> $ git fetch --prune
> ```
>
> This will update your references to the origin repository and also clean the stale branches reported by git branch -r.

```
git push --prune git@example.com:/new-location.git +refs/remotes/origin/*:refs/heads/* +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
```

See

> **Finally, mirroring the repository to a new location**
>
> Now we’re ready to send those updated references back to the origin repository:
>
> ```
> $ git push --prune git@example.com:/new-location.git +refs/remotes/origin/*:refs/heads/* +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
> ```
>
> Ok, what just happened here?!
>
> We want those references inside the .git/refs/remotes/origin to be the LOCAL references in the new location. The local references there will be stored in the refs/heads dir. Same thing happens to tags.
>
> The `+` sign indicates that we want to overwrite any reference there may already exist.
>
> `--prune` means we want to delete any reference that may exist there if we don’t have such reference in our `refs/remotes/origin/*` (and tags) references.

and I guess regarding LFS you would do a

```
git lfs push --all https:example.com/new-repository.git
```

Comment: prune and gif lfs didn’t work

Comment: What exactly does "didn't work" mean?

Comment: So I tried using prune, but same error appear, if I use prune appart push, prune worked but when I try to push, it's the same (missing) problem

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53428807/361177):

> That error means that your Git push contains a reference to a Git LFS object that was never uploaded to the server. **(obviously)**.
>
> Try to run `git lfs push origin --all` to upload all local Git LFS objects. Afterwards `git push` should work.

Comment: didn’t work either

Comment: What exactly does "didn't work" mean?