# Moving a git repository with lfs to another server without moving lfs

Tags: git, github, azure-devops, git-lfs

I have a git repo on Azure DevOps with LFS on Artifactory.
I want to move the repo to GitHub without touching LFS.
The error I keep getting is:

> Your push referenced at least 240 unknown Git LFS objects:

I checked and all the objects are there...
What I tried:

```
git clone <azure devops repo>
git lfs fetch --all origin
git remote add new-origin <github repo>
git lfs push new-origin --all
git push -u new-origin --all --force
```

The git lfs push DOES work and reports 100% 240/240
So I don't understand why GitHub is rejecting the push
I also tried

```
git push --mirror new-origin
```

Same result

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason why GitHub is rejecting your push is that some of the LFS objects are missing from Artifactory, or that GitHub cannot access them. You can check by running below commands on your local repository:

```
git lfs ls-files
```

Compare the output with the LFS objects stored in Artifactory. Use command `git add --renormalize path/to/file` for a fix. Please refer to the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52614132/14996050) for the details.

Another possible reason is that you are using different LFS endpoints for the source and the destination servers. This can cause conflicts when pushing the LFS objects to GitHub. Try command:

```
git config --list | grep lfs
```

And check for lfs.url, please refer to the [link](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/3231#issuecomment-419351132) for your reference.

Comment: LFS endpoints are the same. I did check the lfs files list. The IDs match. Also, when I do lfs fetch it does work, so the files are definitely there and git can get them.

Comment: To narrow down the issue, please change the target github repo, try to push to another devops git repo as target one, will the command work?

Comment: @MickeyCohen, may i know if there's any update?

Comment: zhou adding the .lfsconfig solved the push problem. But becuase we are working from multiple locations using different instances of Artifactory with replication, this is not the best option. We need the lfs url config to come from the client who is cloning/fetching. How can this be achieved?

Comment: @MickeyCohen, thanks for your sharing! Since `.lfsconfig` stores on the root directory of the repo, for your scenario, i suppose you have to update the `.lfsconfig` file to make sure correct instances of Artifactory is tracked before your push.

Comment: I'm afraid this does not help. We need people from multiple location to clone without having to change the .lfsconfig each time

Comment: If the .lfsconfig cannot be changed in different location, i suppose it could not be able to use different instances of Artifactory. But you can raise a new ticket with details to get more help.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `.lfsconfig` in the root of your repository, then add

```
[lfs]
    url = https://link-to-the-repo-with-large-files
```

Once you commit that change, `git push -f` to github. If that doesnt work, try `GIT_LFS_SKIP_PUSH=1 git push origin main --force`